# Infinite sets with bijection are strongly minimal

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I'm working through Tent and Ziegler "[A Course in Model Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/course-in-model-theory/7A4C7BCF0F243AE31C0923A021A06066)" and I got stuck on the Exercise 5.7.2:

> Show that the theory of an infinite set equipped with a
> bijection without finite cycles is strongly minimal and that the associated
> geometry is trivial.

I think I understand how to do the trivial geometry part. For the strong minimality, however, I do not know how to get quantifier elimination, which seems to be the key to the problem. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a good picture in your mind of what an arbitrary model of this theory looks like? What about an arbitrary substructure of a model? If so, it's pretty straightforward to apply a standard test for QE like Theorem 3.2.5 in Tent and Ziegler.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I do not have such intuition, unfortunately. Do you have in mind using b) of Theorem 3.2.5 in Tent&Ziegler? I do not see what the common substructure in that case would be, especially if the models are to be elementarily equivalent (is this theory complete, so that all models are elementarily equivalent either way?)

Comment: A few comments: (1) Regarding intuition. *Hint*: For each element of a model, think about the orbit of that element under the bijection $f$ and its inverse $f^{-1}$. What does that orbit look like? Now every model decomposes into a disjoint union of orbits... (2) I have in mind using (c) of Theorem 3.2.5, which gives a very concrete criterion for QE, in that it reduces to primitive existential formulas. (3) "I do not see what the common substructure would be" The test for QE says that you need to consider an *arbitrary* common substructure of two models of $T$. For example, the two models ...

Comment: ... could have some particular element and its forward orbit under $f$ in common. (4) "Is this theory complete, so that all models are elementarily equivalent either way?" Yes, it turns out that this theory is complete, but of course you have to prove this. But note that Theorem 3.2.5(b) asks for the models $M^1$ and $M^2$ to be elementarily equivalent in the language with additional constant symbols naming the elements of the common substructure $A$. This is stronger than merely saying that $M^1$ and $M^2$ are elementarily equivalent (not every complete theory has QE).

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you for your exhaustive comments! Ad. (1): Sadly, I am only an undergrad, so I do not know the notion of  an orbit—quick googling [shows](encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Orbit) it is a notion from group theory, which I am not familiar with; the index of Tent and Ziegler does not mention it either, so I believe it is possible to solve the problem without it. Hence, for (3) I also do not undertstand what you mean by "forward orbit" (I understand the _arbitrary_ part and my mistake).

Comment: By "the orbit of $a$ under $f$ and $f^{-1}$", I mean $\{f^n(a)\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, where, e.g., $f^3(a) = f(f(f(a)))$. By "the forward orbit of $a$ under $f$", I mean $\{f^n(a)\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{f\}$, the language of a unary function, and let $T$ be the theory of a bijection without finite cycles. We first show that $T$ eliminates quantifiers; by, eg, lemma 3.2.4. of Tent and Ziegler, it suffices to consider primitive existential formulas.  There are no constant symbols in our language, so the only terms are of the form $f^n(v)$ for some $n\in\omega$ and some variable $v$, where we use the notation indicated by Alex in his comments. Additionally, the only relation symbol in our language is equality, so the only atomic formulas are of the form $f^m(v)=f^n(w)$. Thus, any conjunction of atomic formulas and their negations will be of the form $$\phi(\overline{v})\wedge\left(\bigwedge_{l=1}^af^{m'_l}(w)=f^{m_l}(v_{i_l})\right)\wedge\left(\bigwedge_{l=1}^{b}f^{n'_l}(w)\neq f^{n_l}(v_{j_l})\right)\wedge\psi(w)$$ where $\psi$ and $\phi$ are themselves quantifier-free and of the same form as the two conjuncts in the middle. Now, denoting by $\theta(v_1,\dots,v_k,w)$ the formula above, we wish to show that $\exists w\theta$ is equivalent to a quantifier-free formula, modulo $T$.

First we claim that we can ignore $\psi(w)$; indeed, if $\psi(w)$ contains any conjunct of the shape $f^m(w)\neq f^m(w)$, then $\exists w\theta$ will of course be unsatisfiable and so equivalent to $\bot$. On the other hand, consider the case where $\psi(w)$ contains any conjunct of the shape $f^m(w)=f^n(w)$ for $m\neq n$. Any value of $w$ satisfying this formula would be part of a finite cycle, of cycle length dividing $m-n$. Since models of $T$ have no finite cycles, in this case $\exists w\theta$ is again equivalent to $\bot$. Conversely, if $\psi$ does not contain any conjuncts of the above two forms, then *every* element of a model of $T$ will satisfy it, and so we may safely omit it from considerations. Indeed, in this case every conjunct of $\psi$ will be of form $f^m(w)=f^m(w)$ (clearly satisfied by any element of a model of $T$) or $f^m(w)\neq f^n(w)$ for $m\neq n$ (again satisfied by any element of a model of $T$, since such models have no finite $f$-cycles).

Thus it suffices to consider the case where $\theta$ has an empty $\psi(w)$ term. Since $f$ is a bijection, we may replace each $m_l$ in $\theta$ with $m_l-m_l'$ and each $n_l$ in $\theta$ with $n_l-n_l'$ and hence assume that each $m'_l=0$ and $n'_l=0$. (Note, however, that this means $m_l$ and $n_l$ may be negative, so the corresponding expression may not be an $\mathcal{L}$-formula.)

Now, because any model of $T$ has infinitely many elements, if $a=0$ then $\exists w\theta$ will be equivalent to $\phi(\overline{v})$. Thus we may assume $a>0$, and then we have that $\exists w\theta$ is equivalent to $$\phi(\overline{v})\wedge\left(f^{m_1}(v_{i_1})=\dots=f^{m_a}(v_{i_a})\right)\wedge\left(\bigwedge_{l=1}^b f^{m_1}(v_{i_1})\neq f^{n_l}(v_{j_i})\right).$$ Now, since there may be negative values of $m_l$ and $n_l$, this will not necessarily be an $\mathcal{L}$-formula. However, if there are negative values of $m_l$ and $n_l$, then we may simply apply $f$ a total of $|\min\{m_1,\dots,m_a,n_1,\dots,n_b\}|$ times to every term and thence obtain an $\mathcal{L}$-formula. Since $f$ is a bijection, the resulting formula will be logically equivalent to the original.

---

It follows immediately that $T$ is strongly minimal. Indeed, if $M\models T$, then by quantifier elimination (and the fact that $\mathcal{L}$ has no relation symbols) every $\mathcal{L}_M$-formula in one free variable will cut out a boolean combination of finite sets, and thus be either finite or cofinite, as desired.

Comment: +1. But you've forgotten the possibility of atomic formulas of the form $f^n(w) = f^m(w)$. Dealing with these and their negations is where we use the fact that there are no cycles.

Comment: @AlexKruckman oops, you are of course right!! thank you – have corrected now :)